# Best way to pull similar items from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, similarity

I have a database of items (articles for that matter).
What I'd like to do, is I'd like to pull X items that are similar to a specific item, based on two things - title, which is the title of the article, and tags, which are located in another table.

The structure is as follows (relevant fields only):

Table: article
Fields: articleid, title

Table: tag
Fields: tagid, tagtext

Table: articletag
Fields: tagid, articleid

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You're going to have to give a more specific explanation of what you consider "similar"

Comment: @Derek Kromm Similar - items that have a similar title (I was thinking MATCH AGAINST, then order by score) and matching tags (not required, obviously).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640495/search-for-matching-tags-similarity-search-with-mysql-and-constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For myisam tables you can use Natural Language Full-Text search:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

```
SELECT * FROM article a
LEFT JOIN articletag at ON (at.articleid = a.articleid)
LEFT JOIN tag t ON (at.tagid = t.tagid)
WHERE MATCH (a.title) AGAINST ('some title' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
OR MATCH (t.tagtext) AGAINST ('some tag' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
GROUP BY a.articleid # if you don't want get duplicates
```

You can also think about adding redundant information about tags into one field (e.g. `<taga><tagb><tagz>`) in article table and update it each time tag is added/removed. This will simplify query and it should be faster:

```
SELECT * FROM article a
WHERE MATCH (a.title, a.tagtext) AGAINST ('some title or tag' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Comment: I'm looking to get SIMILAR items.

Comment: To use `FULLTEXT` _and stay based on tags_, you would need to construct the `AGAINST` string from the original list of tags.