# Search for matching tags (Similarity Search) with MySQL and Constraints

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

this is my first thread. I apologize if this is a duplicate, but then i was not able to search for the right keywords.

My Problem:
There are tagged items on a website. On a detailed view of a item e.g. http://localhost/items/a.html i want to show a list of similar/related items based on their tags.

- Item A-Tags

  - Labor
  - Chemie
  - Analytik
  - Mehrweg
- Item B-Tags

  - Labor
  - Chemie
  - quantitativ
  - Laktose
- Item C-Tags

  - quantitativ
  - abscheiden
  - Flaschenpfand

The **Structure** of the tables: (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300183/best-way-to-pull-similar-items-from-a-mysql-database))

Table: article
Fields: articleid, title

Table: tag
Fields: tagid, tagtext

Table: articletag
Fields: tagid, articleid

When I now visit following entry point (http://localhost/items/b.html) for item B i want to print a list to the user which show the related items in this order:

- Item A (because of two same tags)
- Item C (because of one same tag)

As i searched in google i found something like this:
[How to compare two comma-separated string lists using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935750/how-to-compare-two-comma-separated-string-lists-using-mysql)

It looks just as my problem, but i didn't see any hints how to solve that for my query. The most other post that i found would just exclude item a and c because they dont match all of the tags (item a doesnt match for the tag qantitativ and Laktose)

Which further information do you need? 
Btw: I will not add all tags as a extra property to the items table due to be able to perform a match against on this column. I just don't want to update this tags always when the tags changes. This is just doubling  the size of saved data in the db.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  c.articleid, COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM articletag AS b
    JOIN articletag AS c  ON c.tagid = b.tagid
                         AND c.articleid != b.articleid
    WHERE b.articleid = 123
    GROUP BY c.articleid
    ORDER BY ct DESC;
```

When searching for what is 'similar' to 123 (Item-B in your example),
the output should

```
Item-A, 2
Item-C, 1
```

This is a full scan of `articletag`.  So, heed the tips in my discussion of [*many:many mapping*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .

If you need to get information about the articles after performing the query, use it as a 'derived' table; for example:

```
SELECT articles.*
    FROM ( the above SELECT ) AS x
    JOIN articles USING(articleid)
    ORDER BY x.ct DESC;
```

(You can remove the `ORDER BY` from the inner query, since it will be ignored in preference to the outer `ORDER BY`.)